# Which car was Tony Stark driving in the end of Iron Man 3?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man-3

As the title says, which car was Tony Stark driving in the end of *Iron Man 3*? It looks like a high-end Lamborghini or something, but is it a real model or just made up for the movie to look futuristic?

To clarify, the scene in question is exactly at the end of the movie when Tony goes to the ruins of his house and then leaves with the car and some junk in the trailer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This car seen in the final scene is an [Audi e-tron](http://ironman.wikia.com/wiki/Audi_R8_e-tron_(Red)).

[image]
[image]

Holy product placement, Iron Man!

[image]

Comment: Damn, how did I miss that? Also, that was really fast, you're awesome, thanks!

Comment: I think this may be the same car he drives in the ending of _Avengers_, but those cars all look the same to me.

Comment: Oh, no, [it isn't](https://youtu.be/zXPJ6xFvdWk?t=1m59s).

Comment: @Gallifreyan - That was, of course an [Acura NSX Roadster](http://www.imcdb.org/vehicle_525885-Acura-NSX-Roadster-Concept-2012.html). It wasn't a real car, but was in fact a 1991 Acura NSX with a fancy (Hollywood) poly-carbon shell. It wouldn't be road legal since it has zero impact protection.